# selenium page opens empty

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to open the following page, it loads empty, looks like js is not parsed. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.Get("https://www.realestate.com.au/")
```

Comment: do other websites work fine? how about [example.com](https://example.com)?

Comment: Yes other websites work, only this one doesn't

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Yarin_007, please try other websites so that we can rule out https://www.realestate.com.au/ being the cause of the issue (however, I was able to access it on Selenium, so I doubt it), provide the full code ran (of course, that is not entirely necessary since your two lines provides enough), and provide a log of the output. Here are some possible fixes:

1. An immediate area to check is if JavaScript execution is actually enabled: ensure that JavaScript execution is enabled in your WebDriver instance. By default, WebDriver should execute JavaScript, but it's worth checking if there are any settings that might be preventing it.
2. Also check that the version of Chrome WebDriver you are using is compatible with the version of Chrome installed on your system. Incompatible versions can cause issues with JavaScript execution.
3. Finally, it is possible that the page you are loading might take some time to load all the necessary JavaScript and content. You can try adding a wait before interacting with the page to ensure that it has fully loaded.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    
    # Open the webpage
    driver.get("https://www.realestate.com.au/")
    
    # Add a wait to ensure that the page has fully loaded
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "body")))
```